# Why is the use of lightning in modern day characters usually associated with villains and/or with being bad?

Tags: star-wars, marvel, avatar-the-last-airbender, greek-myth, norse-gods

Think about it: Electro from Spiderman, the Emperor from Star Wars, Zuko's sister Princess Azula from the Airbender series all use lightning and are considered almost explicitly to be bad. I'm sure there are other examples as well, these three came to mind. The two other examples are Thor (Marvel) and Pikachu from Pokemon, but Thor is taken from Norse Mythology and Pikachu is a (mouse?) Pokemon. Both Thor and Zeus, two of the main lightning wielders of the past were on the side of good. Why the switch in the modern age?

Comment: Good Guys with electrical powers would be hired by the electric company to power cities.

Comment: @Oldcat [You're not the first one to think of that.](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Republic_City_power_plant)

Comment: I'm not seeing the "evil" exclusivity here. Lightning is associated with destructive, uncontrolled power. It's at least frightening, but barely a pattern at all.

Comment: Pikachu is far more recent than Electro or Papaltine.

Comment: I would vote to close this question on the basis of it being a question that cannot be seriously answered with anything other than conjecture (at best).

Comment: Re: Airbender; while Azula wielded lightning, so did Zuko and Iroh. Lightning is not "evil," but rather "difficult to control." Only the most skilled firebenders could produce and control lightning; Azula's use of it was not an attempt to show how evil she was, but rather a display of her firebending ability. As for other lightning users, I'd like to point at both Static Shock (from the cartoon by the same title), and Storm (from X-Men). _Warmachine_ has an entire faction of lightning-friendly characters, who are the "good guys" from their point of view.

Comment: I was going to mention Storm, too, alongside Brennan Mulwray (_Mutant X_) and of course Tristan Thorn (_Stardust_) and Yoda (_Attack of the Clones_).  The premise of the question is distinctly faulty.

Comment: It's not strictly correct to paint Zeus with a modern dualist palette of good and evil, either.

Comment: @JdeBP - Yoda didn't use force lightning, he merely reflected it back at its user

Comment: I'm not sure I would classify Zeus as good. Philandering rapist a-hole. Never mind Prometheus story.

Answer (score 5):

**Summary: Lightning is unpredictable and powerful making it a poor choice for someone who cares about who they target.** And bad guys are less likely to care about who they maim.

In classical mythology, Thor and Zeus weren't "good guys". People assumed Thor was protector of Earth because of the violence in the sky, and the fact that the Earth wasn't torn assunder, he must be protecting them.

And, Zeus, he was just as likely to bless you as he was to smite you, turn into a swan and get with your wife.

As for why lightening is considered a "bad" power, firstly look at this photo of lightening generated from the static electricity from a plume of ash in a volcano.

[image: Frightening Lightening]

Powerful, and frightening right? There is a reason many people (including me) and animals suffer from [Brontophobia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astraphobia) - or fear of lightning. One other factor is that lightening is impossible to predict. Because of the fact that lightning is such a chaotic and powerful phenomena [explains why many religions revered it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning_in_religion).

So as an ability that one can control it is very powerful and very chaotic. You might get your target, you might get the innocent bystander standing near by. If you're a "good" guy, you might care about about who you hurt. If you are the "bad" guy you likely don't care if your caped meddler gets hurt or their plucky sidekick.